# How to apply rma() normalization to a unique CEL file?

Tags: r, bioconductor, batch-normalization

I have implemented a R script that performs batch correction on a gene expression dataset. To do the batch correction, I first need to normalize the data in each CEL file through the [Affy rma() function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/affy/versions/1.50.0/topics/rma) of Bioconductor.

If I run it on the [GSE59867 dataset](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE59867) obtained from GEO, everything works.
I define a batch as the data collection date: I put all the CEL files having the same date into a specific folder, and then consider that date/folder as a specific batch.
On the [GSE59867 dataset](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE59867), a batch/folder contains only 1 CEL file. Nonetheless, the `rma()` function works on it perfectly.

But, instead, if I try to run my script on another dataset ([GSE36809](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE36809)), I have some troubles: if I try to apply the `rma()` function to a batch/folder containing only 1 file, I get the following error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "GSM901376_c23583161.CEL.gz") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Here's my specific R code, to let you understand.
You first have to download the file [GSM901376_c23583161.CEL.gz](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM901376):

```
setwd(".")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fileURL <- "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/samples/GSM901nnn/GSM901376/suppl/GSM901376%5Fc23583161%2ECEL%2Egz"
fileDownloadCommand <- paste("wget ", fileURL, " ", sep="")
system(fileDownloadCommand)
```

Library installation:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")    
list.of.packages <- c("easypackages")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)    
listOfBiocPackages <- c("oligo", "affyio","BiocParallel")

bioCpackagesNotInstalled <- which( !listOfBiocPackages %in% rownames(installed.packages()) )
cat("package missing listOfBiocPackages[", bioCpackagesNotInstalled, "]: ", listOfBiocPackages[bioCpackagesNotInstalled], "\n", sep="")

if( length(bioCpackagesNotInstalled) ) {
    biocLite(listOfBiocPackages[bioCpackagesNotInstalled])
}

library("easypackages")
libraries(list.of.packages)
libraries(listOfBiocPackages)
```

Application of rma()

```
thisFileDate <- "GSM901376_c23583161.CEL.gz"
thisDateRawData <- read.celfiles(thisDateCelFiles)
thisDateNormData <- rma(thisDateRawData)
```

After the call to `rma()`, I get the error.
How can I solve this problem?

I also tried to skip this normalization, by saving the `thisDateRawData` object directly. But then I have the problem that I cannot combine together this `thisDateRawData` (that is a `ExpressionFeatureSet`) with the outputs of rma() (that are `ExpressionSet` objects).

(**EDIT**: I extensively edited the question, and added a piece of R code you should be able to run on your pc.)

Comment: Firstly, this is a very specific Bioinformatics/Bioconductor question; as much as I can relate to your issue, I'm not sure whether SO is the right forum for such a question. Secondly, you should always clearly state which non-base R libraries you are using. For example, `read.celfiles` is from `oligo`; `rma` is from `affy`. Please include relevant calls in your code, i.e. `library(oligo); library(affy)`.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question at the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org/).

Comment: Thirdly, the GEO files you link to are very large (1.8 Gb and 6.0 Gb, respectively). I don't think you'll have much luck finding people willing to download nearly 8 Gb of data to reproduce your issue. Is there a way for you to share a minimal subset of the data? And lastly: `ExpressionSet` is what `rma` returns *post* probe-summarisation. Asking how to convert a `GeneFeatureSet` to an `ExpressionSet` for use in `rma` makes no sense. You need a `*FeatureSet` (with the emphasis on "feature") for RMA.

Comment: I had a quick look: Both `affy` and `oligo` provide an `rma` function; `oligo::rma` accepts both `ExpressionFeatureSet` and `GeneFeatureSet`. Be sure to not load both `affy` and `oligo`; or explicitly specify `rma` as `oligo::rma`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for your comments. My question actually was badly asked; I completely re-wrote it and added a piece of code that should run on your pc. Let me know if you can help me again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. This is a puzzling problem. the `oligo::rma()` function might be buggy for class GeneFeatureSet with single samples. I got it to work with a single sample by using lower-level functions, but it means I also had to create the expression set from scratch by specifying the slots:

```
# source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("GEOquery")
# biocLite("pd.hg.u133.plus.2")
# biocLite("pd.hugene.1.0.st.v1")
library(GEOquery)
library(oligo)

# # Instead of using .gz files, I extracted the actual CELs.
# # This is just to illustrate how I read in the files; your usage will differ.
# projectDir <- ""  # Path to .tar files here
# setwd(projectDir)
# untar("GSE36809_RAW.tar", exdir = "GSE36809")
# untar("GSE59867_RAW.tar", exdir = "GSE59867")
# setwd("GSE36809"); gse3_cels <- dir()
# sapply(paste(gse3_cels, sep = "/"), gunzip); setwd(projectDir)
# setwd("GSE59867"); gse5_cels <- dir()
# sapply(paste(gse5_cels, sep = "/"), gunzip); setwd(projectDir)
#
# Read in CEL
#
# setwd("GSE36809"); gse3_cels <- dir()
# gse3_efs <- read.celfiles(gse3_cels[1])

# # Assuming you've read in the CEL files as a GeneFeatureSet or 
# # ExpressionFeatureSet object (i.e. gse3_efs in this example),
# # you can now fit the RMA and create an ExpressionSet object with it:

exprsData <- basicRMA(exprs(gse3_efs), pnVec = featureNames(gse3_efs))
gse3_expset <- new("ExpressionSet")
slot(gse3_expset, "assayData") <- assayDataNew(exprs = exprsData)
slot(gse3_expset, "phenoData") <- phenoData(gse3_efs)
slot(gse3_expset, "featureData") <- annotatedDataFrameFrom(attr(gse3_expset, 
  'assayData'), byrow = TRUE)
slot(gse3_expset, "protocolData") <- protocolData(gse3_efs)
slot(gse3_expset, "annotation") <- slot(gse3_efs, "annotation")
```

Hopefully the above approach will work in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Paggles01 for your answer. Where should I insert your piece of code in my script? And what should I do with the `gse3_expset` variable then?

Comment: Insert it after you've created the `GeneFeatureSet` object (that's `gse3_efs` in my example) from your CEL file(s). I assumed that if you're analyzing the data you'd want to create an `ExpressionSet`, which is what `gse3_expset` is in this example. If all you wanted was the rma data, then you could stop at the creation of `exprsData` with `basicRMA()`. You could, for instance, save the rma data as an `.RData` file to the folder with your chip(s) data. Update if the solution still doesn't work in your code.

Comment: Hi @Paggles01, thanks a lot! It apparently worked out :-) It also generated these warnings, when I use the combine() function to merge togethere an output of `rma()` and your `gse3_expset`: `Warning messages:
1: In alleq(levels(x[[nm]]), levels(y[[nm]])) :
  Lengths (2, 1) differ (string compare on first 1)1 string mismatch
2: data frame column 'exprs' levels not all.equal 
3: In alleq(levels(x[[nm]]), levels(y[[nm]])) :
  Lengths (2, 1) differ (string compare on first 1)1 string mismatch
4: data frame column 'dates' levels not all.equal ` Do you know how to remove them? Thanks!

Comment: A warning is just that -- a warning. But it raises the question of why you want to combine the outputs of `rma()` (I assume form the other GEO set?) and `gse3_expset`. The CEL files for these two sets come from two different chip platforms and much of the data are not directly comparable. Without getting into the specifics of your study design (not really a topic for SO), be careful about what you try to analyze. Also, I'm not well-versed in the RMA literature, but if you're RMA normalizing samples based on different chips you may want to verify whether they should be analyzed together at all.